Whatsapp Package conflication between com.whatsapp and com.whatsapp.w4b
even though the whatsapp is installed in my system but still it gets into catch clause
   public String isPackageExisted(String targetPackage) {
        
     //   targetPackage="com.whatsapp";
        
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            try {
                PackageInfo info=pm.getPackageInfo(targetPackage,PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
                    return targetPackage;
                } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                    return "com.whatsapp.w4b";
                }
        }


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The issue you are facing is probably due to security reasons, although I cannot be certain without knowing the specific exception that was thrown.
If it is some security exception then, you'll need to do the following:
AndroidManifest.xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  <queries>
    <package android:name="com.whatsapp"/>
    <package android:name="com.whatsapp.w4b"/>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent>
  </queries>
... rest of the manifest

PackageHelper.java
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;

public class PackageHelper {

    public static PackageInfo getPackageInfo(Context context, String packageName) {
        try {
            if (AndroidVersionHelper.isQOrAbove()) {
                return context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    packageName,
                    PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS
                );
            } else {
                return context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

And use PackageHelper.java as:
PackageInfo waBPackageInfo = PackageHelper.getPackageInfo(context, "com.whatsapp.w4b")
PackageInfo waPackageInfo = PackageHelper.getPackageInfo(context, "com.whatsapp")

